# IMAP migration and changes to folder structure

Tags: email, imap, dovecot

I am using imapcopy on a ubuntu 14.04 server and telnet to migrate and respectively edit heavy imap inboxes accounts. I would like to flatten the folder structure, meaning that I want to select and copy all emails from all children folders into one "Import" folder.

I cant seem to be able to do just that. Any suggestions to an alternative way to do this?

Comment: Is the dovecot server the destination ? do you have disk access on it  ?

Comment: @igael unfortunately not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using this? https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/imapcopy/1.04-1.  If so, edit imaptools.pas and change the following line as shown to copy all messages to the IMPORT folder on the destination.

Original:

```
Result := Command ('APPEND '+Mailbox + Flags + ' {' + IntToStr (Length(Msg)) + '}',TRUE);
```

New:

```
Result := Command ('APPEND IMPORT' + Flags + ' {' + IntToStr (Length(Msg)) + '}',TRUE);
```

If the IMPORT folder does not already exist you'll need to create it.

```
Err := Dst.CreateMailbox ('IMPORT');
```

Then recompile it.

Comment: Worked like a charm! Thank you Rick!!

Answer (score 0):

You can use https://github.com/Schluggi/pymap-copy as well. I think this is more handsome, because you don't have to compile anything.

If you would like it as described above (copy every mail of every subfolder to the  import folder):

```
./pymap-copy.py \
--source-user=user1 \
--source-server=server1.example.org \
--source-pass=2345678 \
--destination-user=user2 \
--destination-server=server2.example.info \
--destination-pass=abcdef \
--redirect *:INBOX.import
```

And in the case you want to maintain your folder structure:

```
./pymap-copy.py \
--source-user=user1 \
--source-server=server1.example.org \
--source-pass=2345678 \
--destination-user=user2 \
--destination-server=server2.example.info \
--destination-pass=abcdef \
--destination-root INBOX.import
```